Wicked PDF doesn't generate correct content
My pdf is generated from a piece of html text, but sometimes it will genreate errors.
I can still see the full html but the pdf is corrupted
This error does not occur continuously.
Can someone please tell me what could be causing this error.
I use a font set imported from outside
HTML and my PDF
    @font-face {
      font-family: MS Mincho;
      font-style: normal;
      src: url('<%= Rails.root.join('public', 'assets', 'fonts', 'MS-Mincho.ttf.woff') %>') format('woff')
    }

    @font-face {
      font-family: MS Gothic;
      src: url('<%= Rails.root.join('public', 'assets', 'fonts', 'MSGOTHIC.TTF') %>') format('TrueType');
      font-weight: 700;
      font-style: normal;
    }

I want to can generate full content
